# .Classes next to the namespase in a class

Tags: c#, class

I get this strange thing when I create a new class, Next to the namespace name I get a .Classes which all I can tell prevents me from creating an instance of the class and hides it.

I would include the screen shot but im not sure how I do this. Please help so you can better understand the question.

Thanks

Comment: How are you creating the class? Are you using Visual Studio? Right-click > Add > Class? Would the folder you're right-clicking on happen to be "Classes"?

Comment: Yes it is a floder I called classes, why didn't I think of that, so why dose it do that ?

Comment: @Jody Stocks VS [uses folder names as class names](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSNamespaces.aspx). So don't name your folder "Classes", give it a meaningful name, e.g. "Security" or "Logging" etc. Separate your code by (business) logic, not filetype.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace within Visual Studio will depend on two things:

1. The default namespace defined within the project properties.
2. The folder structure within your project.

I think that within your project you have a folder *Classes* where you put (*well as the name guesses*) your classes. Due to this fact Visual Studio will automatically append this name to the default namespace.

So either manually change the namespace manually right after you added a new class or move the file one level up within your folder structure of the project.